What causes the property 'results' does not exist on type error in this Angular 16 app?
I have been working on an SPA with Angular 16, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).
In app\services\movie-service.service.ts I have:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../models/Movie';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MovieService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getMovies(): Observable<MovieResponse[]> {
    return this.http.get<MovieResponse[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/now_playing?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }
}

The model app\models\Movie.ts looks like this:
export interface Movie {
    id?: number;
    adult?: boolean;
    backdrop_path?: string;
    poster_path?: string;
    title?: string;
    tagline?: string;
    overview?: string;
    genre_ids?: any;
    original_title?: string;
    release_date?: string;
    runtime?: number;
    vote_average?: string;
}

export interface MovieResponse {
    results?: Movie[];
    total_pages?: number;
    total_results?: number;
    page?: number;
}

In the HomePageComponent I try to output the movies:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../../models/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.scss']
})
export class HomePageComponent {

  public movieResponse!: MovieResponse[];

  public movies: Movie[] = [];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  public getMovies() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe((response) => {
      this.movieResponse = response;

      console.log(this.movieResponse);

      this.movies = this.movieResponse.results;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovies();
  }
}

The line console.log(this.movieResponse) coreclly shows the response with the results arary, total_pages, etc;
The problem
The line this.movies = this.movieResponse.results causes the error:
TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'MovieResponse[]'.

Questions

What am I doing wrong?
What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?


The movieResponse has an array of objects ( movie response ) each has its own results property!
Since the request payload is not shared, we can just access the results of the first element!
You can just access one element in the array, instead of accessing the whole array!
  public getMovies() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe((response) => {
      this.movieResponse = response;

      console.log(this.movieResponse);

      this.movies = this.movieResponse[0].results; // <-  changed here!
    })
  }


If from the API you receive only one movie response, then you need to change the code to below. Where we can replace MovieResponse[] with MovieResponse
  public getMovies(): Observable<MovieResponse> {
    return this.http.get<MovieResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/now_playing?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }

ts
export class HomePageComponent {

  public movieResponse!: MovieResponse;

  public movies: Movie[] = [];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  public getMovies() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe((response) => {
      this.movieResponse = response;

      console.log(this.movieResponse);

      this.movies = this.movieResponse.results;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovies();
  }
}


Please try answering this question too. Thanks!
